# Get JS variables from controller type @RequestParam ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>

Tags: java, spring

[image]

There's a JS variable, just like in the image.
I'd like to get this from the controller, but I am getting following error

> org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:
>   Requested List Parameter 'param' is not present?

```
@RequestMapping("updateServiceData")
public @ResponseBody void updateServiceData(@RequestParam 
List<HashMap<String,Object>> param, HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response) {


}


method.serviceUpdateEvent = function(){


    var param = [];
    $(".serviceData tr").each(function(trIndex){
        var serviceData = {};
        if (trIndex === 0) return;
        $(this).find('input').each (function(inputIndex) {
            serviceData[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
        });
        $(this).find('select').each (function(selectIndex) {
            serviceData[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
        });

        param.push(serviceData);                

    });

    console.log(param);
    $.ajax({
        url:'updateServiceData',
        data: param,
        method: 'post',
        success: function(){
        }
    });

};
html ===>for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
                listHtml += "<tr>";
                listHtml +=     "<input type='hidden' name='listId' value='"+list[i].id+"'>";
                listHtml +=     "<td><input type='text' name='roomName' value="+list[i].roomName+" numId='roomName"+list[i].id+"' readOnly></td>";
                listHtml +=     "<td><input type='text' name='roomType' value="+list[i].roomType+" numId='roomType"+list[i].id+"' readOnly></td>";
                listHtml +=     "<td><select class='channel-selectbox-ancillaryService' name='ancillaryService' numId='ancillaryService"+list[i].id+"' value="+list[i].ancillaryService+" onChange='serviceChange(this.value,"+list[i].id+")'></td>";
                listHtml +=     "<td><input type='text' name='quantity' value="+list[i].quantity+" numId='quantity"+list[i].id+"' readOnly></td>";
                listHtml +=     "<td><input type='text' name='personnel' value="+list[i].personnel+" numId='personnel"+list[i].id+"' readOnly></td>";
                listHtml +=     "<td><input type='text' name='price' value="+list[i].price+" numId='price"+list[i].id+"' readOnly></td>";
                listHtml +=     "<td><select class='channel-selectbox-registration' name='registration' numId='registration"+list[i].id+"' disabled='true' style='background:#f1f1f1;'>";
                listHtml +=         "<option value='0'>없음</option>";
                listHtml +=         "<option value='1'>숙박일자별</option>";
                listHtml +=         "<option value='2'>입실일자</option>";
                listHtml +=     "</td>";
                listHtml +=     "<td><input type='text' name='remark' value='"+list[i].remark+"' numId='remark"+list[i].id+"' readOnly></td>";
                listHtml += "</tr>";
            }
```

Comment: Please post your controller code. Are you using POST to send this object from the client side?

Comment: Attached is the code.

Comment: Can you please post details of JSON Object which you are passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@RequestParam` is for url query parameters, which are normally used with GET requests. You need to bind the json payload of the post request to your java objects - try using `@RequestBody` for that. As in:

```
   @RequestMapping("updateServiceData")
   public @ResponseBody void updateServiceData(@RequstBody 
   List<HashMap<String,Object>> param, HttpServletRequest request, 
   HttpServletResponse response)
```

A better practice which is less error prone would be using POJOs as beans, allowing spring to map your jsons to a type safe class - as in `ArrayList< PojoDataContainer>`.

Also, consider using `@PostMapping` rather than `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)`, `@RequestMapping` defaults to GET requests.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my life.

Comment: Sure thing. Again, a better idea would be to create a java object that you can map the jsons in the list to rather than using a map of objects. Try reading up on beans and json binding. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here method you used in Javascript is POST but in the controller, you have used GET.Please use POST , instead of request param use it as request body.

Comment: The same problem occurs even though the change is made. ㅜ_ㅜ

Comment: Better try it with RequestBody